# How to list files on directory shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I need to list the files on Directory. But only true files, not the folders. 
Just couldn't find a way to test if the file is a folder or a directory....

Could some one provide a pice o script for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)?

To find regular files in the current directory and output a sorted list:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort
```

To find anything that is *not a directory* (Note: there are more things than just regular files and directories in Unix-like systems):

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 ! -type d | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` shell `test -f $file` will tell you if $file is a file:

```
if test -f $file; then echo "File"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ls -l | grep ^d -v` to realize what you want. I tested it in Redhat 9.0, it lists only the true files, including the Hidden Files.

If u want to get a list the folders on Directory. But only folders, not the true files. You can use `ls -l | grep ^d`

Comment: No, please don't. There much less brittle approaches around.